# An interaction to show an item is swappable

Tags: interaction-design

In videogames, we often see a little swirl used to show that items are swappable. Do you think this is easy for users to understand? Is there a better way to show that one item can be traded with another user for one of their items?

[image: Swap button]

Comment: You could have a preview of the swap when the cursor is over the new item with an additional effect of semi-transparent over the two items to show that the swap has not been done yet.

Comment: you can show animation by changing items position

Comment: A little bit of an unrelated question:why did Danny Varod replied to the question as a comment and not as an answer ? If I refer to the stack exchange help : you should comment to "request clarification, leave a constructive criticism or add minor information" and should NOT comment to "answer a question"  (and other stuff).

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two items, I can suggest a toggle switch like the O/I of Android.

Answer (score 0):

Another common pattern is to show one item in a slot, to indicate that this is the item that is currently equipped, with the other item being the one that can be slotted in.

Comment: Can you post an example of this? Sounds cool

Answer (score 0):

As well as the "two single arrows" that you illustrate, there is also the curved double-ended arrow that can suggest swappability, e.g.

[image: curved double-ended blue arrow between green square and purple oval]